C# Testing ClassLibary with Nunit - Mising references
I have a classlibary project which i want to test.
When adding a new (Nunit) test project to the solution I get a list of reference errors:

This is my project structure

Test file is rather simple:

using NUnit.Framework;
namespace ClasslibaryTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Add_AddsTwoNumbers_ReturnsSum()
        {
            // Act
            var result = 2;

            // Assert
            Assert.Equals(3, result);
        }
    }
}


So why am I getting all these assembly, attribute and reference errors and how can I fix it?

did you run a nuget restore or dotnet restore?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain i did after reading you comment, but no change

Why do you reference test assemblies in your class library project? I would expect to see those only in your test project.

It sounds like there is a clash, possibly between your .NET Core project's properties and an AssemblyInfo.cs file in the same project. See this article for some suggested resolutions. As a quick
test, you could try deleting the AssemblyInfo.cs file for the complaining project to see whether that makes the errors go away.
